# .htaccess file rules are disturbing the menubar layout when window goes on mobile view

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working over a project which is built in core-PHP. I have a menu-bar whose all menus, when the website open into mobile view, gets consolidated into single button. When u click on that button it expands & all menus can be seen. I am facing problem when i add the .htaccess rule for URL rewriting like following way:

```
RewriteRule ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ log-in.php?temporaryBookingId=$1&jSessionId=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ log-in.php?temporaryBookingId=$1&jSessionId=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

Here after adding the rule the site works fine no doubt in that. Problem is when i open it in mobile view their on clicking the menu-bar button, it doesn't expands. When i removed the rules and tried then it worked well. Why this is occurring? Anyone who faced this issue?

Thanks in advance for quick response over this

Here is the GIF recording of my project page where i have user the .htaccess rule

http://g.recordit.co/uVKEfXV2xR.gif

Its been a month long i have faced this issue and unable to find the relevance of this with anything else of my project.

Comment: That is quite abnormal, are you sure that nothing else is causing this? Or that there are no other network requests to scripts or XHRs that are getting broken by this rule, thus breaking script execution?

Comment: I really don't know what is happening here. I faced this problem for the first time & getting stuck here

Comment: Do some good, old-fashioned diffs. compare output of every script and network request with and without the rules enabled and see what's changed. Otherwise, I haven't a clue.

Comment: @Shaggie:- Can you check weather your css is getting loaded fine?
As per your gif I can see that when you access /login url the menu is working fine and when you access login/12345/12345 the menu doesn't work but I see a small white box below the menu button can you check what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it's not directly an .htaccess problem.

When you use a .htaccess redirection, please make sure your css and javascript files are loaded with their absolute path.
Do not use :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="relative/path/file.js"></script>
```

use one of this solutions :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/absolute/path/file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourwebsite.com/absolute/path/file.js"></script>
```

I think you call your javascript file with its relative path, and the problem is, in the case where the menu-bar does not expand, this script has a 404 error.

You can track which file(s) are not loaded by using your browser's webmaster network tools when you change the URL, and then use the absolute path for that file.

Comment: Holy shit.....! It was an issue with javascript loading when i pass parametric url via .htaccess rule! I haven't looked at it coz i thought if it is loading with /login then it will be loaded as well with /login/12345/12345. Thank a loooooooot @tic_le_kiwi. You saved me finally

Answer (score 0):

Try using only first rule with R=301 at end

```
RewriteRule ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ log-in.php?temporaryBookingId=$1&jSessionId=$2 [R=301,L]
```

because second rule is overwriting your first rule and not matching your criteria path i.e : "login/12345/12345".

Comment: Generally if there are any JS issues we can check in browsers 'console'. As the author 'shaggie' mentioned in the question that "When i removed the rules and tried then it worked well." , this issue might occur due to the rewriterule else has to check any css / js issues in mobile view